# Problem while storing accented characters to the database using spring framework

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, spring, stored-procedures, non-ascii-characters

I am using a stored procedure to insert some data to the SQL 2005 DB using Spring Framework's stored procedure class. The class declaration is somewhat like:

```
       private class InsertShippingAddress extends StoredProcedure {
    public InsertShippingAddress(final DataSource ds) {
      super(ds, "usp_adiPromoInsertShippingDetail");
      super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_FirstName", Types.VARCHAR));

      compile();
    }
  }
```

I'm executing the SP like:

```
     final InsertShippingAddress insertShippingAddress = new InsertShippingAddress(
            getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());
    final Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    inParams.put("in_FirstName", name);
   insertShippingAddress.execute(inParams);
```

now the problem is, the name string containg accented characters in french language, but while the storage the string èüÀÔàé is getting stored as e`u¨A`O^a`e´ in a distorted manner. But if I actually go and execute the SP through SQL management studio, it saves correctly. I don't know where am I going wrong. Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Narain

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not a java programmer

The problem may be in this line

```
  super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_FirstName", Types.VARCHAR));
```

since you're using a the `VARCHAR` type, non-ASCII characters may not be correctly converted.

Perhaps you should be using the following?

```
  super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_FirstName", Types.NVARCHAR));
```

**EDIT**

If you can't use the `NVARCHAR` type, one work-around might be to cast the string to hex then pass it to the database as `Types.VARBINARY` (or something similar) - the database should handle type conversion correctly. I have no idea if Spring will let you do this.

Comment: unfortunately Types.NVARCHAR is not available, there's only Types.LONGVARCHAR which is not of much use in my case.

Comment: Types.NVARCHAR is only in Java 1.6. Can you upgrade?